# Заглавная буква Ы

Tags: общие-вопросы

Здравствуйте, детенышу в школе после буквенного диктанта (1 класс) отметили как ошибку написание заглавной буквы "Ы". "Такой буквы не существует" - вердикт учителя. Поверить? А как написать "Ким Чен Ын"? Да, русских слов на "Ы" я не знаю, но утверждать, что заглавной буквы не существует, правильно ли это? Спасибо.

Comment: знаете, после того как я получила в электронном журнале:
 p.s.: 
Каждый день прибавляются новые забытые вещи: 
юбка в клеточку 1шт, 
розовый пинал 1 шт, 
колготки 7шт, 
майки 4шт, 
синий кардиган 1 шт, 
полосатый шарф 1шт, 
куча носков.

Comment: или такое:
Вырастить плесень. Задача: провести опыт- взять два кусочка хлеба( 1-в пакете, 2- открытый) и посмотреть, где вырастит плесень и сделать вывод. То же самое можно проделать с заваркой чая. 

я стала внимательно следить за процессом обучения. нет! не внимательно - настороженно.
в учебнике по окружающему миру, например, пожарные называются пожарниками.
а букварь можно читать со сцены: (готовы?)
Лама нору мирно рыла,
На луну уныло ныла.
Мул малину мылом мыл
И рулоны уронил.

Comment: >например, пожарные называются пожарниками  
  
Это нормально. Современное значение слова вполне такое допускает.

Вот букварь - это да... Что-то с чем-то... И даже ударение в "нору" явно не на месте.))) А что за изобретение "Электронный журнал"? Моя дочке школу закончила так давно, что уже и говорить о том неудобно... Разве от внуков когда-нибудь, Бог даст, узнаю.

Comment: Ыгыатта - есть такая река где-то на севере Сибири.

Comment: 
doroty, ваш  редактор  разве  орфографические  ошибки  не  подчёркивает ?  Пенал,  вырастет  плесень...

Comment: >ваш редактор разве орфографические ошибки не подчёркивает ?  
  
>Пенал   
  
***???***
  
>вырастит       
      
А что, ваш подчеркивает?   
  
>плесень.    
  
***???***

Comment: вы, наверное, не так меня поняли, но в этом виновата сама - не поставила кавычки. к сожалению, эти послания в дневнике от УЧИТЕЛЕЙ! (и пИнал, и вырастИт) - вот в чем весь ужас. а когда я получила СМС от тренера по тхэквандо - сразу забрала детей из секции :). не смогу процитировать - поверьте, с первого раза даже смысла не поняла.

Comment: Из всего только "плесень" - да и то спорно.
а пИнал, и вырастИт - разве нет таких слов?

Comment: не очень понятен ваш комментарий, но спасибо, что уделили мне время.

Comment: >не очень понятен ваш комментарий, но спасибо, что уделили мне время.   
  
Это я не вам "время уделил". Это товарищу, который думает, что спелл-чекер (который он называет "редактором") способен "подчеркнуть" слова "пинал" и "вырастит". Это же нормальные слова, только попавшие "не на свое место".

Типа:
*"Я его пинал за то, что он не понял, как ребенок вырастит плесень".* 
Ну и где этот сверхумный редактор?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению, учителя иногда в "методических целях" говорят неправду. Наверное, думают, что так проще что-то объяснить "этим оболтусам". В данном случае - донести тот факт, что с неё не начинаются слова... Интересно, а если бы в классе был кореец или уроженец, например, якутского поселка Ыныкчанский?

Ребенку надо как-то объяснить, что её не существует "в школе", а во взрослой жизни она может встретиться.

А вообще он молодец. Рассказал о школьных приколах родителю (родительнице?). И родитель у него молодец. Выслушал и понял правильно. 
(+)
Интересно, а учителка клавиатуру компьютерную когда-нибудь видела? Интересно было бы услышать её объяснения.

Answer (score 3):

Это, конечно, она оговорилась. Буква существует, но русские слова с неё не начинаются. Она же не знала, что ребёнок расскажет об этом родителям, поэтому не очень думала, что говорит.

Comment: Всё-таки  лучше  думать,  особенно  учителю.

Answer (score 3):

Заглавная буква "Ы" существует, вот, я её в кавычках и написала. И есть русские слова, которые с этой буквы начинаются - в первую очередь это глагол "Ыкать", который имеет значение "то и дело произносить звук "ы", а далее - производные от него, вроде "Ыканье", "Ыкая" и тому подобные. Следует заметить, что при этом нельзя считать звук [ы] вариантом звука [и], так как со звуком [и] это будут слова с совершенно другим значением: "икать", "иканье", "икая" и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Слова на Ы начинаются и ещё как!!!
Лидер КНДР Ким Чен Ын;

Ыал-Усуга — посёлок в Якутии в междуречьи рек Тумара и Келе, впадающих в Алдан; 63,35 °с. ш. и 130,05 °в. д.;

Ыллымах — посёлок в Южной Якутии в 55 км к ЮЮВ от г. Томмот; ок. 59 °с. ш. и 127 °в. д. и т. д.
[**Ы! Именно так! заглавная буква ы!** | doost-z.livejournal.com](http://doost-z.livejournal.com/69584.html)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, КАК  **сейчас**  учат современных "детенышей". Но в пресловутое советское время по поводу  **первой буквы**  было только два ограничения: слово  **не может**  начинаться с мягкого или твердого знака! Это автоматически означало, что любая другая буква — и **Ы** в том числе — имеет право быть заглавной.

Не поленилась, взяла атлас мира, а там:
Ыспарта — город в Турции (400тысяч жителей, между прочим), Ыштык, Ытык-Кюёль, Ымсон, Ыгыатта, Ыйрён...

В Эстонии, где я живу, достаточно особенных названий, которые никак не вписываются в правила русского языка:
**Йыхви, Йыгева, Нарва-Йыэсуу, Выртсъярв, Эмайыги, Йизаку, Лаймъяла,**    **Муствеэ, Ыйсмяэ, Ыхтулехт...** — **они** (города, река, озеро, газета...)  **есть** вне зависимости от оговорок, методических целей и придумываемых кем-то "правил".

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, необязательно знать многочисленные «Ыллымах» и «Ыал-Усуг». Достаточно вспомнить о [Паровозе Ъ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7_%D0%AA), и сразу станет ясно, что именем собственным может быть что угодно.

А если вспомнить ещё и о аббревиатурах (которые могут быть составлены разными неочевидными способами), то получим корректное предложение:

> Гуляя во дворе, дети выдумали ОАО «ЬЭЩЫ» и уже распределили все акции.